# Links in NSTableView NSCell

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nscell

I have been reading and experimenting with allowing links in a custom drawn NSCell for the last few days and have basically got nothing usable, there's always issues with each approach.

Does anyone know of a way of doing this that works?

I am custom drawing the NSCell using - (void)drawInteriorWithFrame:(NSRect)theCellFrame inView:(NSView *)theControlViewm

The NSCell is just a variable height block of text with links inside it, some cells have links, some do not.

I've tried using nsattributedstring with NSLinkAttributeName

I've tried intercepting all hits to the cell and then trying to match up where they clicked to where the link would be in the text but that never works out.

I've basically tried all suggestions that I could find on all boards but most comments are old so I'm hoping someone has figured out a good way to do this.

Thanks, David

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried this exactly, but give this a try:

First, for hyperlinks I use a category on NSAttributedString, akin to this [post](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2006/qa1487.html) from Apple developer docs. The example here gives you a method on NSAttributedString 'hyperlinkFromString:withURL:`

Second, create a delegate for the table, and implement `tableView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row:` method.

In that method,

`setAttributedStringValue:[NSAttributedString hyperlinkFromString:YOUR_STRING withURL:YOUR_URL]`

or, if you need non-hyperlinked string text as well,

`setAttributedStringValue:[SOME_NON_HYPERLINKED_STRING appendAttributedString:[NSAttributedString hyperlinkFromString:YOUR_STRING withURL:YOUR_URL]]`

If that is the only reason you are custom drawing an NSCell, you can try getting rid of your custom class, because this should work with an NSTextFieldCell. I've seen online, though, that some people have had trouble with centering attributed strings in text field cells, so I hope it works ok. One other caveat: with the delegate method, be sure that you set the cell attribute that you are changing for all conditions. I quote:

> Because aCell is reused for every row in aTableColumn, the delegate must set the display attributes both when drawing special cells and when drawing normal cells.

from "http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html" (sorry, StackOverflow won't let me post more than one hyperlink yet)

Hope this helps.

Comment: The question is not how to draw the links, which is trivial, but how to make the links clickable.